# com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback cannot be resolved

Tags: android, google-maps, screenshot

I have been using GoogleMaps V2 for some time in my app, all working just fine. Now I want to add a Screenshot feature and for that I'm going to use the SnapshotReadyCallback.

But when I add:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback;
```

I get

```
The import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback cannot be resolved.
```

I've been googling for answers, but can't seem to find one that helps.
Target is set to Google API's API Level 8

I've tried cleaning all project etc.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What version of the library do you use?

Comment: Then Android SDK Manager in Eclipse says Rev 19.0.1 for Android Support Library

Answer (score 0):

You need to update Google Service from

> SDK Manager > Extras > Google service

In Google Service rev 7, I can't import `GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback`; after updating to rev 15, I can.